# Extracting audio from video in matlab. The audio is de-accelerated

Tags: matlab, audio, video

The input video length is 1min 56sec and Ouput audio length comes out to be 2 min 47 sec

```
    file1='vipmen1.wav'; %o/p file name
    hmfr=video.MultimediaFileReader(file_fullpath,'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',false);
    hmfw = video.MultimediaFileWriter(file1,'AudioInputPort',true,'FileFormat','WAV');
    while ~isDone(hmfr)
       audioFrame = step(hmfr);
       step(hmfw,audioFrame);
    end
    close(hmfw);
    close(hmfr);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: question obviously is why it is de accelerated.. ? i need a normal audio output as video's output

Comment: This is probably related to different sample frequencies for audio and video. Check the sampling rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the same sample rate for your output. Read the sample rate from the input and use this rate to write the output.

Comment: can you pls help me how to read a sample rate from a video input? and also how to write it to output? with a sample code?

Comment: That's explained in the documentation. For the reader check ".info"